# Mongodb update using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I need help in updating MONGO DB. here is my document:

```
Functions : {
    "cgi0-app" : { 
        "calculatedConfigValues" : { 
            "floor" : 0.0 , 
            "ceiling" : 49.0 , 
            "calculatedBrokenValue" : 2.033 }, 
        "userConfigValues" : null }, 
    "shop-app" : { 
        "calculatedConfigValues" : { 
            "floor" : 0.0 , 
            "ceiling" : 70.0 , 
            "calculatedBrokenValue" : 2.413 } } }
```

I am trying to update shop-app's "ceiling" value from 70 to 100 in MongoDB, but not successful. Here is my Code:

```
BasicDBObject find = new BasicDBObject("Functions.shop app.calculatedConfigValues.floor",0);

BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("Functions.shop-        app.calculatedConfigValues.$.ceiling", 100);

getDB().update(find, set);
```

Can someone please help me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really create DBObjects with that dot notation. You have to nest new BasicDBObjects for each level in the document tree.

```
DBObject toFind = new BasicDBObject("Functions", 
    new BasicDBObject("show-app", 
        new BasicDBObject("calculatedConfigValues", 
            new BasicDBObject("floor", 0))));
```

Same for the update object

```
DBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set",
    new BasicDBObject("Functions", 
        new BasicDBObject("show-app", 
            new BasicDBObject("calculatedConfigValues",
                new BasicDBObject("ceiling", 100)))))
```

Alternatively, you can use [this](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.1/com/mongodb/util/JSON.html) Helper class for translating json strings into DBObject structures like this.

```
DBObject toFind = (DBObject) JSON.parse(
    "{'Functions.show-app.calculatedConfigValues.floor':0}"
);
```

But be aware of that using the JSON class may cause performance problems. It's simply faster to build DBObjects manually.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but don't you want to update a specific document within a collection within the DB? So something along these lines:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongo.getDB(DB_NAME);
db.getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME).update(find, set);
```

I would also define find in this way, because you want the specific object from that collection.

```
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
obj.put(..., 0);
DBObject find = db.getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME).findOne(obj);
```

Let me know if this works.